# Parse JSON In Inno setup with Json parser

Tags: json, inno-setup, pascal

In my Inno setup project, I need to parse a JSON. I Try to create a dll and parse JSON with the dll function but it gives me an access violation error after two days I could not find the reason for this access violation so I decide to parse JSON inside the Inno Setup.
I want to parse this JSON and Use the [JsonParser library](https://github.com/koldev/JsonParser)  also here is two similar Questions
but I couldn't get it.

[How to parse a JSON string in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290115/how-to-parse-a-json-string-in-inno-setup)

[JSON arrays in inno setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965804/json-arrays-in-inno-setup)

```
{
 "Header":"Install FileType",

 "Files":  
 [
   {
    "Filename":"SQL Server",
    "FileType": 1,
    "CheckExists":true,    
  },
  {
    "Filename":"Dot Net 3.5",
    "FileType": 2,
    "CheckExists":false,  
  }

 ]
}
```

I need this function

```
type
 TJFile = record 
   FileName : string;
   FileType : Integer;
   CheckExists: Boolean;

GetFile(JSON: string; Index :Integer; var File: TJFile );
```

how can parse Json to get File with its index. Thank you for help and guid me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pascal Script, so I cannot really answer your question, but I notice that your JSON sample is not valid: there shouldn't be a comma after "true" (line 9), neither after "false" (line 14).